# How to show avatar of current logged in user in a widget

Tags: widgets, avatar, globals

I have a php widget, and I need to show the avatar of the current logged in user, and I'm calling this code: `<?php echo get_avatar(); ?>`
But its only outputting the default avatar.

Is there a global I need to add above it?

Answer (score 1):

This should work great... in this example i am using wordpress codex so you can comapre:

**From Wordpress Codex**

```
<?php echo get_avatar( $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt ); ?>
```

so... Based on that...

**This is the code you should embed in the desired location in your theme:**

```
<?php
    wp_get_current_user();
    $size = array(60,60); // this is the size of the avatar
    echo get_avatar( $current_user->user_email, $size, $default, $current_user->display_name );
?>
```

.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: it should work mate.. are you sure you are logged in? hmm.. try to enter this after wp_get_current_user();  --THIS-->  
    
echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . '<br />';

Comment: nope. not working

Comment: Noting echoes? not even the plain text meaning 'User email:' i guess your not pasting that code in a place that would result in the apearnce of the thumb niether the text i gave you in order to check...